# CParserError when using github to store CSVs

Tags: python, pandas, github

My script loads panda-written-CSVs for analysis and charting and it works well when the files are stored locally. I loaded the csvs to my [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11493) but when trying to load them, I'm getting:

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 31, saw 3

I'm aware of the read csv parsing issue as [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11493) and tried the solutions proposed, but again, the problem is specific to the use of github to store the files. Any ideas??

```
dir_path='https://github.com/ronyarmon/SFO/tree/master/Data/questions/'
```

data_dfs_dict={}

questions=['Airport as a whole', 'Signs & directions inside SFO','Accessing & using free WiFi','Restaurants',
           'Retail shops & concessions', 'Information on screens/monitors','Escalators/Elevators/Moving walkways',
           'Information booths-Baggage claim','Information booths-Departure area','AirTrain',
           'Signs & directions-Roadways','Airport parking facilities','Long term parking lot shuttle',
           'Airport rental car center','Artwork and exhibitions']

question_files_names=['ALL','SIGN','WIFI','FOOD','STORE','SCREENS','WALKWAYS', 'INFODOWN','INFOUP',
                      'AIRTRAIN','ROADS','PARK','LTPARKING','RENTAL','ART']

for index,value in enumerate(question_files_names):
    file_name=value+'.csv'
    file_path=dir_path+file_name
    print (index, value)
    data_dfs_dict[questions[index]]=pd.read_csv(file_path)
    #data_dfs_dict[questions[index]]=pd.read_csv(file_path,error_bad_lines=False)
options_list=data_dfs_dict.keys()

Comment: What operating system are you using? Could be some end-of-line issue

Comment: Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.3